# Android Studio - No Target Device Found

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I'm having trouble getting an Android app that I developed working on my phone. (`Android Studio` on `Windows 7` trying to run the app on `Samsung Note 3` running `Android 5.0`)

Here's what I've done so far:

- Turned on `USB debugging` and allowed `unknown sources`
- Installed `Google USB Driver`
- Restarted computer
- Tried `updating the driver` for the phone but no updates were available
- Turned on `debugging` in the `build.gradle` file

and yet it is still returning `Error running app: No target device found`

I have also tried the dialog option for when I run the app but that says `No USB devices or running emulators detected`

Is there anything I have missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You device is running an API less than your apps minimum SDK version?

Comment: @cricket_007 No, the minimum API level for my app is 4.0.3, but my devices is running 5.0. Thanks for checking though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up downloading the official Samsung ADB from here: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

And it worked great after that. Thanks everyone!

Comment: How come that this is not needed for some other Samsung devices?

Comment: This was necessary for me on Galaxy S10e, Android 9

Answer (score 57):

1. Go to Run in the toolbar.
2. Select Edit Configurations..
3. On the left panel, you'll see your application (app). On the right under Deployment Target Options choose Target as Open Select Deployment Target Dialog option.
   And the other option as it is.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it for my Samsung Tab 8 running Android Studio 3.x on a Mac after the tablet loaded some update overnight.

Comment: For IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 it's "Run" / "Select Device"

Answer (score 5):

**On the phone**

1. Have you enabled Developer Mode?
2. Have you enabled USB debugging within the Developer Tools menu in settings (this menu doesn't appear unless you've enabled Developer Mode)
3. Do you have a good and securely connected USB cable?

**In Android Studio**

1. In Edit Run/Debug Configurations, do you have "Target: USB Device"?
2. It seems to help me to press the "Attach debugger to Android process" icon (a tall rectangle with a green beetle) and cancelling before pressing the "Debug app" icon

**In Windows**

1. It's helpful to know whether your phone appears as a recognised device.  If you navigate to "ThisPC", (a level above C:), do you see it there?
2. Joel Gritter said he solved this issue by downloading the latest official Samsung ADB, see his answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have tried all of the above as I did, to no avail, you can also force kill the adb.exe in task manager. I had over 40 tries to force close. After that, I restarted the adb to run my app and BOOM. Everything was cool again.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem, so i goto the project folder and deleted .gradle  ,  .idea   and build folder from there and and them open the project again in android studio and clean and rebuild the project and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

(For those who don't find "Deployment target option"  )

1.Go to Navigation bar

2.Device explorer

3.Select Device explorer

4.Re-plug USB (There will be a lot of files from your device )

5.After a while run the app

Hopefully this will work

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in a similar problem. Following the [User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device) I was finally able to solve the issue by downloading and installing the Android SDK Platform-Tools from SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was because of Platform-Tools. I updated that and solved. path:

File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK  -> Android SDK Platform-Tools.

If you have problem with update, remove it from SDK folder manually and then install it again.