# Android Studio: No target device found: Why?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-studio-3.0

When I first start Android Studio opening an existing project, and click "Run", I get the error message "**Error running app, No target device found**".

I have my Samsung plugged in and ADB debugging enabled. It correctly shows up with the "adb devices" command and ADB shell works fine. I tried "adb start-server" with no joy. Strangely, If I start 'Debug app' first and then 'Run' it works fine, but I don't understand why this annoying step is necessary. Other Stack Overflow answers said to do "Edit Configurations" but that doesn't show the options suggested. I'm running AS V3.01. Any clue?

Comment: `Strangely, If I start 'Debug app' first and then 'Run' it works fine` what do you mean?

Comment: Did you waited a time so adb started while no devices apear?

Comment: Yes I waited plenty. And the device *always* appears. But still no joy.

Comment: in my case that was because of Platform-Tools. check my solution here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022679/android-studio-no-target-device-found/71219257#:~:text=In%20my%20case%20that%20was%20because%20of%20Platform%2DTools.%20I%20updated%20that%20and%20solved.%20path%3A%20File%20%7C%20Settings%20%7C%20Appearance%20%26%20Behavior%20%7C%20System%20Settings%20%7C%20Android%20SDK%20%2D%3E%20Android%20SDK%20Platform%2DTools

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found my problem. Under Run->EditConfigurations->DeploymentTargetOptions, I selected **USB Device** (my phone is a USB device, right?). But noooo, when I select **Open Select Deployment Target Dialog**, everything is peachy. Also, checking **Use same device for future launches** bypasses the dialog entirely and all is good.

Comment: Exactly the same issue, and exactly this solution worked for me. StackoverFlow is great!

Comment: If you don't see the `DeploymentTargetOptions` and do have an emulated device created, try restarting Android Studio and it should show up.

Answer (score 0):

- Check USB connection. Might be device is not connected properly.
- Enable USB debugging mode on Device
  [How to enable USB debugging in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android)
- Select your device in tool bar and click on play button(Run
  application).