# Android Studio 3.2 "No target device found"

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, adb, device

I really have no idea what else to do with this.
I did an update on my adb drivers in the Windows Device Manager (or at least it tells me there is no more current version available), as well as an update to the latest sdk version.
Also I installed the Google USB drivers in the sdk tools. 
After none of every suggested steps seemed to work I reinstalled my entire Android Studio hoping this would fix my issues.
I have the most current version of java as well as activated developer and debugging mode on my phone. 
I did restart both my phone and my PC.
So I really do not know why the heck I am still shown this message although having seemingly every requirement fulfilled...
Please help me... 
I'm driving crazy on this :(

Comment: run "adb devices" and see is there a result.

Comment: Sorry but where do i "run" adb devices?

Comment: adb is a command line tool, located in "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\"

Comment: in my case that was because of Platform-Tools. check my solution here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022679/android-studio-no-target-device-found/71219257#:~:text=In%20my%20case%20that%20was%20because%20of%20Platform%2DTools.%20I%20updated%20that%20and%20solved.%20path%3A%20File%20%7C%20Settings%20%7C%20Appearance%20%26%20Behavior%20%7C%20System%20Settings%20%7C%20Android%20SDK%20%2D%3E%20Android%20SDK%20Platform%2DTools

Answer (score 3):

Go to the device manufacturing company website and download corresponding device driver.
And click `Run--Edit Configuration` menu and check options like below:
[image]