# Error running 'app: No target device found. Android Studio 3.6 Preview

Tags: android, android-studio

Aa beginner, failed to run my first Android Application on Android Studio 3.6. How can I make the right setting to see the preview device in the emulator?

I tried the same question and discussion, but failed to solve my problem.[image]

Comment: Did you try to reconnect your device?

Comment: Open the terminal at the bottom and run following commands: 1. adb kill-server 2. adb start-server  3. adb devices. See whether you find your devices after the last command. Make sure USB debugging is enabled in device.

Comment: I do not have physical android device.

Comment: @Mangesh, thanks, but I do not habe real android device.

Comment: are you sure you created  Android Virtual Device?

Comment: Did you successfully clone a device for an emulator?

Comment: adb kill-server command does not exist. !

Comment: Make sure your emulator set up is done properly?

Comment: @pythonbuddha https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb take a look

Comment: Thank you, I need to reconfigure the android virtual device.

Comment: @pythonbuddha As a beginner, you probably shouldn't be using AS 3.6 Preview. Please use AS 3.4 Stable. Also, if you won't take my first statement seriously, at least install Stable to run side-by-side with Preview so you can switch back to Stable should anything block you from continuing on some project in Preview - I know you like the new features (frankly, so do I) and hopefully they will come to Android Studio Stable soon.

Comment: in my case that was because of Platform-Tools. check my solution here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022679/android-studio-no-target-device-found/71219257#:~:text=In%20my%20case%20that%20was%20because%20of%20Platform%2DTools.%20I%20updated%20that%20and%20solved.%20path%3A%20File%20%7C%20Settings%20%7C%20Appearance%20%26%20Behavior%20%7C%20System%20Settings%20%7C%20Android%20SDK%20%2D%3E%20Android%20SDK%20Platform%2DTools

Answer (score 11):

Here's the problem: You don't have any virtual devices. Here's a screenshot of what you probably should have to run (In AS 3.6 Preview):

[image]

Compare this to your picture where it says "No devices". So, I'm going to walk you through creating an AVD.

Now, since  I do have AVDs, I'm just going to create one. click on that drop-down menu that for you says "No devices" and click "Open AVD Manager":

[image]

In the popup click "Create Virtual Device..."

[image]

In the Virtual Device configuration popup select the device you want and click "Next".

[image]

Choose the system image you want (you can go to the other tabs to see what's there) and click "Next"

[image]

Then name your AVD and click "Finish"

[image]

Now you should see your new Android Virtual Device:

[image]

Closing out of it, you can now run your application with the green "Run" arrow!

I hope this helped!

Comment: What if I want my mobile device to connect? I do have developer options on.

Answer (score 0):

First try this-

Go to the bottom left of Android Studio then click on the square (the one which show/hide the tool on the left, bottom and right) then on Designer. A new tab should be on the right part of android studio, with gradle and maven project.

If still doesn't work, try this -

If you double click on your .xml file tab at the top it will maximize the designer window. Then on the left you can drag the window to shrink and it will reveal the palette. Then just click on the tab on the left to open the project window.

Answer (score -1):

After connecting the device , go to Files -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, not when pythonbuddha doesn't have a device