# Edit Configuration pops up when I run a project,ignoring it says Cant start compilation as output path not set

Tags: android-studio

[This dialogue box appears after I click run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lzIG.png)

When I run the android project I downloaded from Android Developers website, the edit configuration dialogue box shows up. When I press run again, it says the configuration is wrong.I am a beginner and have never opened any project (nor made in my android studio) before.

[Appears if I again click run,says incorrect configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYWuU.png)

[Another box after that which asks to set output path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bjNF.png)

I tried adding a configuration named "FragmentBasics" in the Application menu but it doesn't allow me to select the main class.

[The java class doesnt get selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmL3s.png)

Answer (score 0):

(**Tip: Update your Android Studio. It looks like an ancient version... Do that before doing anything else.**)

(**Prerequisites: Create an Android Virtual Device (AVD): [Error running 'app: No target device found. Android Studio 3.6 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805697/error-running-app-no-target-device-found-android-studio-3-6-preview/56810279#56810279)**)

You don't have the right configurations.

(1 Go to the Configuration Dropdown Menu and click Edit Configurations.

[image]

(2 Delete existing configurations (None of the classes in your project have the "main" method declaration)

[image]

(3 Add an "Android" run config

[image]

(4 Fill in config information

[image]

Now you are ready to deploy your app (Assuming you have an AVD).

---

Hope I helped you!

[image]