# Android Studio in VirtualBox can't find USB device

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox

I am running android studio in an Ubuntu virtualBox and i'm getting

`No target device found.` (which is set to USB devices in the configuration)

I have also added my phone to the virtual machine in the settings as you can see in the picture.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the suggestion in [no target device found android studio 2.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499118/no-target-device-found-android-studio-2-1-1)

change the target to "Show Device Chooser Dialog"